# How do I get new fields dynamically from an object in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I need to display the Product field records in a datatable. But if a new field is added to the Product object, the fields should get dynamically added to the datatable. How do I do this in LWC?

Answer (score 5):

Call [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_object_info) on the object, which will include a `fields` attribute

```
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import PRODUCT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Product2';
```

...

```
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: PRODUCT_OBJECT }) productObjectInfo;
```